# How to close merged branches which were not close during merge?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I don't always chose option "close branch after merge" in Bitbucket pull requests. And therefore I have a lot of branches in the merged tab. How can I close them?

Is "delete" the same as "close" for merged branches? What is the difference if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just delete them.

[That is what happens when you use the "close branch after merging" option](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/281273/answers/2823125).